# ¿Porque en el html no pueden verse acentos o ñ?

Tags: angular, bootstrap

Estoy creando un nuevo proyecto de angular con bootstrap, pero mi duda es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya al empezar a declarar las cosas que necesito empiezan a salir símbolos en lugar de la letra con el acento.
Ya hice una investigación a lo cual modifique mi index.html a lo siguiente:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv=”Content-Type” content=”text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1″ />
    <title>Facturas</title>
    <base href="/" />

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
</head>
<body>
    <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
    
</body>
</html>
```

especialmente modifique lo del ISO, pero aun asi sigue saliendo los simbolos raros, a lo cuál no se cual seria la solución ya que en algunos foros mencionan ir agregando letra por letra con el carácter con su acento como en este [link](https://disenowebakus.net/imagenes/articulos/secuencias-especiales-html.jpg) cosa que para nada es buena idea. y no entiendo es la primera vez que sucede, ya que anteriormente lo había echo pero no me había pasado nada similar

Estoy utilizando VS 2022 pero aun poniendo los comentarios aun asi sigue sin surtir efecto al poner UTF-8

la configuración de VS 2020 es esta y asi esta guardando los archivos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por qué el uso de ISO en vez de UTF-8 ?

Comment: tenia el utf-8 pero aun así marcaba ese error

Comment: Entonces vas a tener que hacer el tedioso trabajo que no querías, cambiando letra por letras manualmente, pero con el `UTF-8` siendo que no hay otra solución. Tu HTML ya está infectado con la terrible virus de la codificación.

Comment: el compilador de angular te muestra algún WARN o ERROR?

Comment: Ninguno, simplemente sigue marcando el mismo error sin poder ver los caracteres

Comment: una posibilidad es que tengas tu IDE con encoding ANSI u otra cosa diferente a UTF-8, que IDE utilizas?

Comment: Visual studio 2022, pero ¿Como podría cambiarlo?

Comment: archivo > guardar como.
en la ventana de guardar al lado del botón guardar haces clic en la flecha y le das a guardar con codificación y ahí escoges utf-8
PD: si estaba con otra codificación que no era UTF-8 en este punto deberías verlo

Comment: Si esta en utf-8, actualice mi pregunta

Comment: haz una prueba cambiando de forma manual los errores y si es el caso quizás tengas que hacer lo que te mencionaron que es cambiar en todos lados de forma manual, a veces pasa que al escribir los textos se transforman pero cuando pones la codificación correcta no se escribe de forma automática a esta codificación, por ende, tienes que hacerlo de forma manual en todos lados y ya no debería fallar de nuevo

Comment: YA ESTA LA SOLUCIÓN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUCIÓN:**

La solución fue seguir es [guía](http://www.liangshunet.com/en/202003/567276536.htm), la cual habilita las opciones avanzadas para guardar, este problema no lo tenia en Visual Studio anteriores a la version 2022, con la ayuda de los comentarios me di una idea, lo cual fue tambien indispensable agregar :

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
```

Ahora lo importante es ir revisando HTML por HTML para poder solucionarlo como esta en la guía anterior, ya que probé .net 6.0 si tu colocas información con caracteres soportados por utf-8, Esto no lo tienes que realizar ya que en .net 3.1 (Que es mi caso), vienen con esta opción por defecto : [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y claramente no va a funcionar. entonces tienen que elegir la opción que diga `UTF-8 CON ASIGNATURA`

Answer (score 0):

En el charset debes igualarlo a UTF-8.

En el Head deberias tener lo siguiente:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
```

Con eso bastrá para que te concidere los carácteres mayormente usados.

Comment: sigue igual no hace ninguna diferencia